# BitLocker locks all drives other than C: drive on windows 10 Dell machine

Tags: windows-10, drive, locks, bitlocker

Windows10 asked me to force restart the windows system to install latest updates. After restarting the machine it locks all the drives except C: drive.

I am using Dell with Windows 10. I am able to manage to deactivate the BitLocker for C: drive using below command:
C:>$BLV=Get-BitLockerVolume
C:>Disable-BitLocker -MountPoint $BLV

But for other drives it throw an error like "Disable-BitLocker : This drive is locked by BitLocker Drive Encryption. You must unlock this drive from Control Panel." I have checked the option from Control Panel also but it shows C: drive only and not my other drives.

I have already tried to disable the BitLocker from Bios settings also. I tried to store the BitLocker key also but the same is not matched for any other drive.

[Devices and drives screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl4WT.png)
[Control panel showing only C: Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cpO4.png)

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue? Let me know if you need anymore details.

Comment: Hi Dear, I am also facing the same issue, could you please tell me the solution if you have already resolved the same?

Answer (score -1):

did you try to go to the particular drive that is locked and right click to manage bitlocker and turn off bitlocker?

https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/4-ways-to-remove-or-disable-bitlocker-encryption-on-windows-10.html#way1

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already tried mentioned options but none is worked for me. 'Turn Off BitLocker' option is not available in Windows10 Home edition.